# Saving inside of rectangle in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have something like that - image loaded from file to picturebox1:

[image]

then after pressing button 'SelectArea' i can draw rectangle on loaded picture:

[image]

and finally after pressing another button 'SaveArea' i'd like to save img inside of created rectangle, so as a result i'll have image saved on my drive like this one:

[image]

How to write code which help me do this last step -> save inside of rectangle?

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First new up a Bitmap with the right dimensions

then you create a Graphics-object for this with [Graphics.FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx) and then use the [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktyfbs10.aspx) method on the resulting Graphics-object to draw a section of your large image onto the bitmap.

Finally save the bitmap-object with Save:

```
public static void SaveBitmapPart(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.RectangleF sourceRect, string pathToSave )
{
    using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)sourceRect.Width, (int)sourceRect.Height))
    {
        using (var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0.0f, 0.0f, sourceRect, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        bmp.Save(pathToSave);
    }
}
```

so just call it with:

```
SaveBitmapPart(picturebox1.Image, myRectangle, @"c:\Temp\Test.bmp");
```

Comment: PS you can use the PictureBoxes-Image property as the "image" (first parameter) for this small function.

Comment: Tnx, but i have still problem. When i select rectangle on my picturebox - 640x480, for example rectangle (300x300) then my saved picture is 300x300, but everything from inside rectangle is on top left corner and it's not stretched - just like micro img of inside of rectangle.

Comment: you didn't write nothing about stretching the image nor did your sample sugguest - anyhow it's rather easy - just change the DrawImage-Method to an overload that can handle image-stretching (just look at the MSDN docu - it's very good) - of course you have to the bitmap for your desiered size too)

Comment: I didn't write about it because i didn't want to do this. I'll try to explain problem better ;) Your's solution work. I have selected rectangle 640x480 - it's size od picturebox1. Which i get in result as picture1.jpg with parameteres 640x480. Inside of it there's square 100x100 with my picture, and rest of picture is blank area. This is 100x100 screen is from 640x480 but it's smaller.. like it's not proper scaled.

Comment: Ok - problem was with System.Drawing.Bitmap resolution which by default is = 96 dpi.

Comment: You must explicitly define a target rectangle for DrawImage, otherwise it causes dpi inconsistency if image loaded as png file. Here is correct one: graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceRect.Width, sourceRect.Height), sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);